# Setting delegate to UITextView crashes when typing

Tags: delegates, uitextview, swift4, xcode8

Since upgrading my project to swift 4 I've been having problems with UITextViews. For some strange reason when I apply delegate = self and then type in the textView it crashes. When I remove tevtView.delegate = self it works and I am able to type with no crashes. But then the problem is I'm not able to use delegate methods. Not sure why this is happening when it was working fine before. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

This is the error i get "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException "

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.delegate = self

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share code a bit more.

Comment: post the log cat